# Embedded Linux: Reading bytes from serial port too slow for quicker transfer

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, embedded-linux

I have a microcontroller and an embedded PC. These two communicated via a serial connection and both are receiving and sending data to each other. The baud rate between these two is 38400. Microcontroller and PC have both the same configuration to ensure the communication (8 data bits, 1 stop bit, even parity).

Communication works fine until the microcontroller starts sending messages around every 10 ms. At this point, the sending queue of the microcontroller gets full and overruns. He then sends an error message to the PC (this is how I know, that the sending queue of the microcontroller get overrun, not that of the PC.

Prior to the embedded Linux version of the PC program, the microcontroller had run with a DOS version of the PC program without causing an error. In DOS single bytes are directly read from and written to the serial port (no kernel buffer like in Linux) Since most of the C-code is portable to Linux I try to replicate the DOS behavior of serial port reading and writing in Linux to keep the rest of which processes these single bytes.

I open and initialize the serial port in the PC as follows.

```
fd_mc = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_NOCTTY | O_RDWR /*| O_NONBLOCK*/ /*| O_SYNC*/);
    if(fd_mc == -1)
    {
        perror("Could not open µc port.");
    }
    else 
    {
        struct termios tty;
        memset(&tty, 0, sizeof(tty));
        if ( tcgetattr ( fd_mc, &tty ) != 0 )
        {
            perror("Error getting termios attributes");
        }
        cfsetospeed (&tty, B38400);
        cfsetispeed (&tty, B38400);
        tty.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);     //raw input
        tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;                              //raw output

        tty.c_cflag |= PARENB;      //even parity
        tty.c_cflag &= ~PARODD;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
        tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
        tty.c_cflag |= CS8;

        tty.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

        tcsetattr(fd_mc, TCSANOW, &tty);
     }
```

The code above is a snippet from a function which initializes two serial ports (one of them is the one to the microcontroller).

**Edit:**
Here is the setting of the flow control, there is none.

```
tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;                            //No hardware based flow control
tty.i_cflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);             //no software based flow control
```

Reading from the serial port happens inside a thread with the help of a ring buffer and pollin. This thread is being called inside the main loop. Code below:

```
void *thread_read()
{

    struct sched_param param;
    param.sched_priority = 97;
    int ret_par = 0;
    ret_par = sched_setscheduler(3, SCHED_FIFO, &param);
    if (ret_par == -1) {
        perror("sched_setscheduler");
        return 0;
    }

    struct pollfd poll_fd[2];
    int ret;
    extern struct fifo mc_fifo, serial_fifo;
    ssize_t t;
    char c;

    poll_fd[0].fd = fd_mc;
    poll_fd[0].events = POLLIN;

    poll_fd[1].fd = fd_serial;
    poll_fd[1].events = POLLIN;

    while(1) {
        ret = poll(poll_fd, 2, 10000);

        if(ret == -1) {
            perror("poll");
        }

        if(poll_fd[0].revents & POLLIN) {
            t = read(fd_mc, &c, 1);
            if(t>0) {
                fifo_in(&mc_fifo, c);
            }
        }
        if(poll_fd[1].revents & POLLIN) {
            t = read(fd_serial, &c, 1);
            if(t>0) {
                fifo_in(&serial_fifo, c);
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Call inside the main loop.

```
pthread_t read;
pthread_create(&read, NULL, thread_read, NULL);
```

The function for writing inside the buffer (fifo_in) is

```
int fifo_in(struct fifo *f, char data) 
{
    if( (f->write + 1 == f->read) || (f->read == 0 && f->write + 1 == FIFO_SIZE) ) //checks if write one before read or at the end
    {
        printf("fifo in overflow\n");
        return 0;   //fifo full
    }
    else {
        f->data[f->write] = data;
        f->write++;
//      printf("Byte in: Containing %4d\tData:\t%4d\n", BytesInReceiveBuffer(1), data); //Bytes contained in fifo of mc
        if(f->write >= FIFO_SIZE) {
            f->write = 0;
        }
        return 1;   //success
    }
}
```

What this function basically does is check where the read and write positions are and write `data` inside the buffer if the two positions don't overlap and are more than `+1` away from each other.

When another function needs the bytes inside the ring buffer it calls `GetByte` which reads the bytes from the ring buffer.

GetByte

```
int GetByte(int port)
{
    char c;

    switch(port) {
    case 0:     //COM1
        fifo_out(&serial_fifo,&c);
        break;
    case 1:     //COM2
        fifo_out(&mc_fifo,&c);
        break;
    }
    return (int)c;
}
```

fifo_out

```
int fifo_out(struct fifo *f, char *data) {
    if(f->read == f->write) {
        printf("fifo in overfwrite\n");
        *data = 0;
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        *data = f->data[f->read];
        f->read++;
//      printf("Byte out: Containing %4d\tData:\t%4d\n", BytesInReceiveBuffer(1), *data);
        if(f->read >= FIFO_SIZE) {
            f->read = 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Prior to the Linux porting, everything was sequential in the DOS version.

Ate the moment my best guess is, that `read()` is to slow and at some point you and starts slowing down the reading from the buffer, which again, blocks the calling of the thread. Maybe I am wrong. At the moment I am kinda clueless what exactly the bug is or even how to fix this.

Every good advice is appreciated.

Comment: TL/DR. Increase to 115200.

Comment: You neglect to mention if there is any flow control.  The termios config is incomplete; it neither enables or disables HW or SW flow-control.  Only if there is flow control could the MCU have a transmit buffer overrun.  If there is no flow control, then you completely misunderstand the problem by focusing on the PC read side.

Comment: There is no flow control, I added the part with the setting. If the fault is not on the PC side, where should I investigate? MCU communicated without any Issue with the DOS version. If possible, I would like to keep the rate at 38400.

Comment: Just a thought... how many bytes per message are you sending? With 1 start bit, 8 data bits, 1 parity bit, and 1 stop bit each byte is 11 bits.  At 38400:

(38400 bits/sec) * (1 byte/11 bits) = 3490.90 bytes/sec -> 0.286 ms/byte

Sending a message every 10ms:

A "small" 50 byte message would take 0.286 ms/byte * 50 bytes = ~14 ms (too fast)

A "smaller" 25 byte message would take 0.286 ms/byte * 50 bytes = ~7ms leaving 3ms read/processing time.  Maybe too fast?

Comment: *"I added the part with the setting."* -- Was this already in the code, or did you just *"add"* it today?  If it was already in the code, then why was it not in your original post?  BTW the code is incorrect; IXON, IXOFF, and  IXANY are not flags of the c_cflag member. Re the DOS version: are you overlooking some change to the MCU?  Have you performed a sanity test with the current MCU and that DOS version?

Comment: It was not in the code, at that time I was not aware of these flags. Thank you for the correction regarding the wrong c_cflag. It is now a c_iflag as it should be. I've done a sanity check with the DOS version at it works as indented, no errors in transmission or what so ever.

Comment: If there's no flow control, then there's absolutely nothing to prevent the MCU from transmitting as fast as it can, which could be 34 bytes in 10ms.  You've provided no details on this *"sending queue*" of the MCU and how it might *"get full, overrun, and send an error message to the PC"*.  Make sure the message is not originating from the PC itself.  Your Linux code is very inefficient (e.g. only 1 byte requested per syscall), but that does not inhibit the transmit by the MCU in any way since there is no flow control.

Comment: Again, thank you for your improvement suggestions of my code. I learned a lot following your advice. One part of the problem was the inefficient read as you and wkz pointed out. The message was 110% originating from the MCU (confirmed with scope) and was due to the implementation of a thread by another dev (this thread concurred directly with the main thread and slowed down the sending queue of the PC, which in exchange confused the MCU).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need a fifo in the application? Your serial driver most likely already has quite a large buffer in the kernel (often a page, which is usually 4kB). If this suffices you could radically simplify the implementation by having `GetByte` doing a non-blocking read against the serial device.

If you want to stick with this design, consider reworking your read-loop to read more than byte at a time. As it is now you need two syscalls for every byte read.

You're changing the scheduling class for PID 3, always. This is probably not what you want. Also, this only means that your thread will run once the bytes have landed in the kernels internal buffer (i.e. when `poll` returns). If the bytes are transferred from the hardware FIFO to the buffer by running a job on a workqueue, and that workqueue runs in `SCHED_OTHER` (which most them do), changing the scheduler of your thread will not have the desired effect. Classic priority inversion problem. You might want to audit the kernel driver used by your particular board. Though, if you empty the entire buffer on every `read` this should be less of a problem.

If this code is ever used on an SMP system, you're most like going to want to guard the `read` and `write` pointers with a lock since they are not updated atomically. Threads are hard to get right, have you considered using an event-loop instead? Something like [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I did yesterday. `read()` now gets as many bytes as there are in the kernel buffer and the self-written FIFO is now protected by mutexes. This fixed one part of my problem. Sadly I cannot get rid of the FIFO since the rest of the old DOS code expects single bytes, and rewriting this is something that is not desired by the lead dev. So +1 and thank you for the indirect confirmation of my own thoughts.